# Export to Excel Limitation

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How to export SSRS report data with greater than 32767 characters in excel. I tried to use this solution but I don't know exactly where I want to put it. anybody has some insight:

```
Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",LEFT(Fields!Message.Value,32767),Fields!Message.Value
```

Comment: you can follow this link, it may help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx

Comment: What exactly is in your report? If I recall, the 32767 character limit is on the contents of a cell in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code I found somewhere on the net.

```
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name= "EXCELOPENXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",Left(Fields!Parameters.Value,32767),Fields!Parameters.Value)
```

It worked for me.

Apparently Reporting Services use Office OPEN XML format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx